# Extension Method to append a list of parameters to existing Uri as query

Tags: c#

In Windows Universal, none of the builder classes for web requests are available, nor can I use System.Web.

How would you optimize (shorten, perform) the extension method below, considering the following requirements:

Sample: http://www.foo.com?bar=foo&foobar=bar

- Append a list of key/value parameters as uri parameter
- Encode the parameters for the web
- Append also if the original uri already contains any query parameters (you do not have to check whether there is a identical pair

**How much do you like this implementation ?:**

```
    public static Uri AppendParameters(this Uri uri, IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        var concatenatedParameters = parameters.Select(pair =>
            $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode(pair.Key)}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(pair.Value)}");

        var query = string.Join("&", concatenatedParameters);
        var uriString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri.Query) ?
            uri.OriginalString + $"?{query}" :
            uri.OriginalString + $"&{query}";

        return new Uri(uriString);
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should validate both your arguments for `null` and throw an `ArgumentNullException` accordingly.

```
if (uri == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uri));
}
```

You could add an early return if the parameters collection is empty as there's no work to actually do.

I'd also use the UriBuilder class like this:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
builder.Query = uri.Query != null && uri.Query.Length > 1 
    ? $"{uri.Query.Substring(1)}&{query}"
    : builder.Query = query;

return builder.Uri;
```

It's basically the same, but it looks a little clearer to me. If you don't want to use the builder, you can at least fully interpolate your strings:

```
uri.OriginalString + $"?{query}"
```

Could be

```
$"{uri.OriginalString}?{query}"
```

## Update

> Can you explain why `uri.Query != null && uri.Query.Length > 1` is better than `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri.Query)`

The reason is that `uri.Query` may return just a question mark e.g. in this example:

```
new Uri("http://www.google.com?").Query
// returns "?"
```

If we just checked `null` or `string.Empty` then we could end up with a uri like `https://www.google.com/?&foo=bar`. By checking if the length is greater than 1, we can be sure we won't output a URI with "?&" in it. Although it is valid, it's a bit ugly.

Comment: Can you explain why `uri.Query != null && uri.Query.Length > 1` is better than `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri.Query)`?

Comment: @maxim - `new Uri("http://www.google.com?").Query` returns `?`. I just didn't want to end up with a url like `?&foo=bar`